# Instagram-like Notifications Data Model

Tags: ios, database, iglistkit

I have a data model that is (almost) 1:1 like Instagram where there is a notifications tab that tells you a list of things: who has commented on your post (with the text included), who has liked your post, who has just followed you, and who has just followed you (and isn't someone you follow).

I have mapped out so far what I think needs to happen but I run into a couple of design flaws which I'll list below...

### My Approach

Notifications Table Columns:
UUID (Primary key) by, to, notificationID (foreign key reference to comment, like), postID (foreign key reference to post), notificationText

Follow Table Columns: UUID (Primary Key), by, to

Comment Table Columns:
UUID (Primary Key), PostID (foreign key reference to post), text, UserID (foreign key reference to user who commented)

Like Table Columns:
UUID (Primary Key), by, to

Every time a user makes one of these notifications (comment, like, follow), they'll also create a notification object so I can query the notifications table.

...Note that "by" and "to" are who did the action vs. the targeted user (i.e. I liked someone else's post so it was "by" me, the current user).

## The design flaws:

The issue is that these notifications aren't created equal.  A notification can have four different results: A comment ("So and so has commented: 'OMG THIS IS A COMMENT!'"), a like ("So and so has liked your post"), a follow ("So and so has started following you").

But only comment and like need to show the picture of which the comment or like came from, a follow is just a follow.  So with a follow I don't need a reference to the post or the follow at all and I waste three columns (notificationText, notificationID, postID).

Am I on the right track?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there is no relation between the four tables that you have mentioned. They don't share a a foreign key reference. The only foreign key references I see are to tables that are not one of these fours. So I'd say that this model is the right way to go

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no relation?"  In notifications I have a foreign key reference to comment (at the very least because I need the text from the comment)?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I missed that as the foreign key was not mentioned in their respective tables as well. Even then, since you don't have a foreign key in the follow table, I don't see a problem with your approach.

Comment: Even if notifications doesn't need a reference to the "like" object and inside notificationID or when its a "follow" and notifications doesn't need a reference to either the notificationID/postID??